# Networking a small office with VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, nas, dhcp

Recently I purchased a CISCO RV042 Small Business router with VPN Capability, obviously to allow external connection to this office via VPN to access a NAS where business files are stored.

I am not really an IT professional, but have above average network fundamentals, and am having a hard time with the IT Team.

Setting up the VPN would have been easy enough, however things are complicated by the fact that there are 2 ISPs, which we were using. The current network consisted of 3 routers - one for each ISP, and one with dual WAN which created a combined WIFI to connect. The first two routers were connected to the third, the whole office was connected ahead of the third one-so that network was fail-safe wrt to failure of one ISP.

Office opinion is that this dual ISP thing needs to continue even with VPN. **We have static IP on one of the ISPs.**

Now there are 4 routers - 3 previous and the new one.

The IT guys faced a problem in setting up the VPN citing problems with ip assignment-they suggested make the two networks independant. However this is not easy to use with wired LAN connections, unlike wifi.

So finally the question is -----

```
With these 4 routers -- 
R1 - ISP1 - single WAN Wifi
R2 - ISP2 - single WAN Wifi
R3 - double WAN - extend Wifi
R4 - CISCO RV042 Double WAN loadbalancing with VPN
```

How can a dual WAN VPN network be created? 
Am attaching a snapshot of a block diagram i created..Other views welcome.[image: Lan Block Diagram]

@trpt4him -- The double ISP was to ensure failover mechanism wrt to a working internet, not working VPN. I kind of got your point. The coming "in" path would be defined, since it would come in via the static ip ISP. 
While going out, the dual WAN router may choose any of the lines while sending back the data, since it would load balance? Or since VPN traffic operates over a unique port, i could close off that port of the non-VPN router. The idea being, there is no need for VPN to be fail-safe. VPN can be via ONE line only. Just the general internet for people working inside this office needs to be failsafe. So when the VPN Line is down-External people would not be able to connect to this office. But internal office people would still have internet via the other working line. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how using two WANs with a VPN would even work.  You'd obviously have a different IP/hostname on each ISP, so which one would you connect to when establishing the connection?  Or do you mean, once the connection is established, have the ability to bounce betwen them?  I don't see how that could work without risking the security/integrity of the tunnel.

Comment: Yes, VPN with two ISP connections is a headache. One possible solution to "ease" the configuration is to get both ISPs to give you static IPs (this is easy but may add extra cost to your rental) then you could configure your company domain name to host two subdomains (vpn1.domain.com and vpn2.domain.com) with DNS records pointing to the IP addresses. Your users then use a main and backup VPN...

Comment: If you want a reliable line then you should invest in a leased line or fibre optic... With regular ADSL you get what you pay for. Yes, using two ISPs is good but the problem you are experiencing right now cannot be easily implemented because IP ranges differ between ISPs. You either go for a failover mechanism with different IPs or a more expensive but more reliable single connection...